# Meaning of 当然のように

Tags: meaning

I can understand the usage of 当然のように if it was used e.g. to describe the way that someone said something, but I do not quite understand how to interpret it in the below. What is the difference in nuance that it adds to the fact that there was so response?

「そもそもお前、爆睡していなかったか？」
食前にも一応声を掛けてるんだが、**当然のように**返事はなかった。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

当然のように in this sentence means "naturally" or "unsurprisingly" (used as a [sentence adverb](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825043950/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/sentence-adverbs)).

> …が、当然のように返事はなかった。
> ..., but, unsurprisingly, there was no response (at that point).

当然のように also means "as if it were a matter of course" or "as if it were nothing to him/her", especially when it modifies 言う or similar verbs.